# How can I add an online .css file in my Angular project using its URL address?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass

I have an online repository of CSS files and I want add each one in my project according to the project's special needs.

In particular i have a component that relates with different number ids in the router. I would like to update the component's style every time it renders based on each id reference.

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: When you say "add each one in my project" do you mean add it in such a way that when it is updated on the "online repository" it will be updated for your project (a dynamic link to the css file), or do you simply mean just include a static version of the code at build time?

Comment: provide some code on what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Zachiah I have a component that relates with different number ids in the router. I would like to update the component's style every time it renders based on each id reference

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, you are looking to add a css file put somewhere on the internet. (Please correct me if I am wrong)

The simplest way is to include a link to the CSS file in your index.html file using the  tag.

For example:

```
<head>
  <!-- Link to the external CSS file -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://yourwesbite.com/styles/custom.css">
</head>
```

This will include the above custom.css file throughout your project.

In case you need to include the file only to a specific angular component, you can head back to that component file and import the file to its css/scss file using the

```
@import "https://yourwesbite.com/styles/custom.css"
```